# Fetch rows for the last 6 hours in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I run a Microsoft SQL Server `SELECT` query and have an issue trying to define a specific time range for that query every 6 hours (I am a newer user of SQL Server).

I have an external script calling this SQL Server database every 6 hours, so I only need the newly produced data from the previous 6 hours until the current time.

For example, if my script executes at 6:00pm PST, I only need the data between 12:00 P.M.- 6:00 P.M. for that current day (or the previous day if script cron job falls between a day range.

An example of my query is below

```
SELECT *
FROM        
    (SELECT 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETUTCDATE(), 121 AS Current_SYSTEM_TIME,
         Table1.Column_11,
         Table1.Column_12,
         Table1.Column_13,
         Table2.Column_11,
         Table2.Column_12,
         Table2.Column_13,
         Table3.Column_11,
         Table3.Column_12,
         Table3.Column_13
     FROM 
         Table1
     INNER JOIN 
         Table2 ON (Table1.Column_11 = Table2.Column_11)
     INNER JOIN 
         Table3 ON (Table1.Column_11 = Table3.Column_11)
     WHERE 
         Table3.Column_12 'pass') a
WHERE 
    Table3.Column_13 < 2 
     AND Current_SYSTEM_TIME BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE()
```

Comment: Welcome to Community! Is there any `Time` decision making column in your table?

Comment: @Irfan I do have a column that is the time of the event (i.e. <event_time>).

Comment: Do you have any auto increment or identity column in the table? I always prefer to come with MAX(id) to search newer records by condition like - WHERE ID (transactional table) > MAX(ID) (from destination table).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Community!

Please try below `WHERE` condition in your query with `HOUR(hh)` range.

```
.......
.......
WHERE Table3.Column_13 < 2 AND <event_time> BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, -6, GETUTCDATE()) AND GETUTCDATE()
```

**EDITED**: As per your comment above! Please apply your where condition on `<event_time>` field!

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you @Irfan